# Facebook feed not posted when i remove the application from facebook account

Tags: android, facebook

I have developed one application and integrate the face book application to my app.
In my application I am posting some `feed` to face book without open the facebook feed dialog, which is working fine for me.

My problem is when I remove the application in my facebook account settings and then post the feed to facebook account the feed will not posted and also don't show any error to me. I want to get any error response message from facebook account or show any toast message

> "Logout and then login again".

Because my session is not closed. how to solve this problem?

```
 if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            AsynchrnousFacebook objAsynchtask = new AsynchrnousFacebook();
            objAsynchtask.execute();
        } else {
            loginToFacebook();
        }

 class AsynchrnousFacebook extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", "Testing task App");
            try {
                String response = facebook.request("feed", parameters, "POST");
                Log.i(TAG, "ResponseString:" + response);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be getting an error back if the user has removed your app. See [this doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/) on how to properly handle the different types of errors.

You can also reference the Scrumptious sample application that's shipped with the SDK, which demonstrates the techniques outlined in the above doc, specifically the [handleError()](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/Scrumptious/src/com/facebook/scrumptious/SelectionFragment.java#L490) method in the SelectionFragment class.